# Unity animation not working as desired

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, wait, instantiation

Im trying to make a dynamic menu animation in Unity 2017 (instantiate menu element-> play animation -> wait animation ends -> repeat)

My goal is to create an effect of sequentially adding items one below another, waiting for the last one to finish and then add the next one

This is working fine, but it has a fixed time between menu items:

[image: Desired Effect]

Code:

```cs
IEnumerator GetJsonBrands()
{
    string url = "http://test.com";
    GameObject newObj;

    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        jsonData = www.text;
    }

    JSONNode jsonNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(jsonData);

    int BrandQty = int.Parse(jsonNode["content"]["brands"]);
    bool leftpos = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < BrandQty; i++)
    {
        if (leftpos)
        {
            // Instantiate Left Prefab
            newObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(LeftBrand, transform);
            leftpos = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Instantiate Right Prefab
            newObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(RightBrand, transform);
            leftpos = true;
        }

        Animator anim = newObj.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.Play("test");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        Debug.Log("finished");
    }
}
```

I think this is a more correct solution, but it doesn't work, all the menu items are appearing and animating at the same time:

[image: Wrong effect]

```cs
IEnumerator GetJsonBrands()
{
    string url = "http://test.com";
    GameObject newObj;

    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        jsonData = www.text;
    }

    JSONNode jsonNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(jsonData);

    int BrandQty = int.Parse(jsonNode["content"]["brands"]);
    bool leftpos = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < BrandQty; i++)
    {
        if (leftpos)
        {
            // Instantiate Left Prefab
            newObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(LeftBrand, transform);
            leftpos = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Instantiate Right Prefab
            newObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(RightBrand, transform);
            leftpos = true;
        }

        Animator anim = newObj.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.Play("test");

        //Wait until Animator is done playing
        while (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("test") &&
            anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime < 1.0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("running");
            //Wait every frame until animation has finished
            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("finished");
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not working? You have to be specific what you mean by that....

Comment: My goal is to wait for the last animation end to continue the instantation of the next object

Comment: Note that you have not explained your issue. We know what you want to do but what's happening now with your current code? What's the behavior of your current code? What about the `Debug.Log`?

Comment: I just edited my post i hope it is more explained now